# Abrir un formulario dentro de un pagecontrol en Delphi

Tags: formularios, delphi

Quisiera poder abrir distintos formularios dentro de un `PageControl`
en el formulario principal, en Delphi

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo declarando formularios adicionales, al momento de crear una nueva instancia del formulario adicional utilizas el propio formulario que lo va a contener como el propietario (AOwner), en seguida declaras al TabSheet que lo mostrará como el padre de la nueva instancia creada, finalmente muestras el formulario, no proporcionas mas información así que supongo que quieres mostrar el formulario dentro de toda la extensión del TabSheet, así que maximizalo.

El siguiente código te puede ayudar:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A : TForm2;
begin
  A := TForm2.Create(Self);
  A.Parent := TabSheet1;
  A.Show;
  A.WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

No olvides quitar el borde a los formulario adicionales *BorderStyle := bsNone*, y tomar en cuenta los mecanismos de destrucción de los formularios adicionales, en ocasiones pueden hacer uso de la memoria de maneras no deseadas.

Creo tener una idea de lo que pretendes hacer, y te recomendaría utilizar mejor Frames en lugar de ventanas adicionales. Pero esa ya es tu decisión.